# MySQL: Merge tables, run SELECT and update duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, duplicates

I've the following three tables:

Table A:

```
id VARCHAR(32) | value VARCHAR(32) | groupId INT
abcdef         | myValue1          | 1
ghijkl         | myValue2          | 2
mnopqr         | myValue3          | 1
```

Table B:

```
id VARCHAR(32) | value VARCHAR(32) | userId INT
abcdef         | myValue4          | 1
uvwxyz         | anotherValue      | 1
```

Table C:

```
id VARCHAR(32) | someOtherColumns...
abcdef
ghijkl
mnopqr
...
uvwxyz
```

Table A and B are used for a m:n-association, thus the "id"-column in both tables references the same field ("id"-column in table c).
What I want to do is (for instance)... select all entries in table A `where groupId = 1`

`SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE groupId = 1`

and also select all entries in table B `where userId = 1`

```
SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE userId = 1
```

That's all no problem... but the following makes the select-statement(s) difficult: How can I merge both select-results and replace the value of the first result? For example:

selecting all entries in Table A `where groupId = 1` I'll get abcdef and also mnopqr.
when I select all entries in Table B where userId = 1 I'll also get abdef (and additionally uvwxyz).

Now, the value of abcdef in Table B should replace the value in the selection result of table A. And the uvwxyz-entry should be added to the result.

Finally I'm looking for a query which produces the following table:

```
id VARCHAR(32) | value VARCHAR(32)
abcdef         | myValue4           -- myValue1 from the select-statement in tableA should be overwritten
mnopqr         | myValue2           -- from table A
uvwxyz         | anotherValue       -- from table B
```

I hope anyone know how to do this... thanks in advance for any suggestion! By the way... it would be great if there is any chance to realize this using one single (long) select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE userId = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE groupId = 1 
       and id not in (select id from TableB where userid = 1)
```

Comment: Wow, pretty simple... I thought about complex join-operations^^ - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

@rs points out to use the UNION, which is required since MySQL doesn't have FULL joins.

Favoring the data from table B is a chose for CASE:

```
select id, case when max(value_b) is not null then max(value_b) else max(value_a) end as final_value
from (
    select id, value as 'value_a', null as 'value_b' from tableA
    union
    select id, null, value from tableB
) ugh
group by 1;
```